# Android Viewflipper Black Screen before last View

Tags: android

Having some difficulty with a viewflipper atm. If I set the viewflipper to the last child view at the start it works and goes to the last view. If I set it to the first view and navigate through the views, it reaches a black screen before the final view.

```
   flip=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
     flip.setInAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
     flip.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
     curdate.setText(currentDate);

     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){
             flip.setDisplayedChild(1);
         }
     });
     next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){
             flip.setDisplayedChild(2);

         }
     });
     next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){

             flip.setDisplayedChild(3);
         }
     });
     previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){
             flip.setDisplayedChild(0);
         }
     });
     previous1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){
             flip.setDisplayedChild(1);
         }
     });
     previous2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
         public void onClick(View view){
             flip.setDisplayedChild(2);
         }
     });
```

As above, the last view should be 3, and if I put flip.setDisplayedCHild(3) before the onClickListeners, it goes to the end and works, but going through normally, it just reaches a black screen.

My xml code is a bit too long to show, but it consists of a ScrollView,a LinearLayout,then a ViewFlipper,and the ViewFlipper's views are all TableLayouts.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old but maybe it will help someone.

It seems that `ViewFlipper` adds some views when it is initialized.

You should call `removeAllViews()` before adding your own views.